# How to make a class variable array

Tags: c++

How do I create an array of a grade class variable. I don't understand how to initialize and what to write in `main()`. from this, is there a way to make a constant? And do I need a for loop to read and output the array? Thanks

```
class First
{
  public:
    int getId();
    void setId(int);
    int getExam();
    void setExam(int);
    void print();
    First(int studentId, int exam);

  private:
    int id;
    int grade;
};

int main()
{
  int studentId = 0;
  int exam = 0;

  First Student(studentId, exam);

  cout << "Enter student id" << endl;
  cin >> studentId;
  Student.setId(studentId);

  cout << "enter grade" << endl;
  cin >> exam;
  Student.setExam(exam);

  Student.print();

  return 0;

}
```

Comment: You declare an array as a class member variable the same way you declare an array anywhere else, such as a local or global variable.

Answer (score 3):

If you know the size of the array at compile-time, this is how you would create the array:

```
First student_list[size];
```

Though it's more ideal to use compile-time classes like [`std::array<T, N>`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/array):

```
#include <array>

std::array<int, size> student_list;
```

If you don't know the size at compile-time, or your compiler doesn't support `std::array`, use [`std::vector<T>`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector):

```
#include <vector>

std::vector<int> student_list;
```

Moreover, your parameterized constructor (`First(int, int)`) overrides the default and copy-constructor that the compiler normally provides. Your default constructor can look like this:

```
First() { }
```

Otherwise you can use the `default` specifier with C++11:

```
First() = default;
```

However, by using default parameters for your specialized constructor, it can act as a default constructor when given 0 arguments. The following is a good alternative:

```
First(int studentid = 0, int exam = 0)
{ }
```

And lastly, yes, you would need some sort of loop to print out each element's grade in succession.

Comment: Also: Need a default constructor, and possibly a copy constructor.

Comment: @user1787000 As Keith said, you will also need to implement a default constructor and a copy constructor, otherwise when you create the array you will get errors because it default constructs each element.

Comment: +1, but I really disagree with the default arguments for the constructor. It is now also a implicitly converting constructor, which is really unfortunate. I'd rather write a default constructor and delegate.